# JSS Dynamic Placeholder - some components are missing

Tags: jss, dynamic-placeholder

I have a component with a `jss-form` placeholder inside it. I added two renderings with different placeholder signatures to make it into a Dynamic Placeholder. These are as follows:

- FormA: `/jss-main/jss-form-{b0898e09-ea46-48b0-becb-03f97a38f493}-0`
- FormB: `/jss-main/jss-form-{b0898e09-ea46-48b0-becb-03f97a38f493}-1`

I have set two placeholder settings on my main component's presentation details

- `jss-main`
- `jss-form`

However, the Layout Service only returns FormA under `jss-form`:
Therefore this:

```
<Placeholder name="jss-form" rendering={rendering} />
<Placeholder name="jss-form" rendering={rendering} />
```

Becomes:

```
<FormA />
<FormA />
```

But if I change the signature of FormB to that of FormA, I get both of them twice!

```
<FormA />
<FormB />
<FormA />
<FormB />
```

I'm using Sitecore 9.3 and I'm doing a Sitecore-first approach with the Embedded JSS application, so I manually create my placeholders and renderings and stuff. Can anyone point out where I did wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is related to `Content Resolver`.
Please verify your code and make sure you selected correct Layout service in your `JSON rendering` as shown in below screenshot

[image]

Comment: This isn't it. I have set my rendering its proper contents resolver though.